# The different constructor ways

Tags: c++, class

I have write little class, now i see different ways to call constructors. Which way is the correct way? (Or the better way)

> SharedKeys.h

```
#ifndef SHAREDKEYS_H
    #define SHAREDKEYS_H

    class SharedKeys
    {
    private:
        char keyCode;

    public:
        SharedKeys(char keycode)
        {
            keyCode = keycode;
        }
        ~SharedKeys() {}

        char getKeyCode() { return keyCode; };

    };

    #endif
```

> Main.cpp

My constructor call way:

```
SharedKeys* SK;
SK = new SharedKeys(*cstr); //Call contructor
```

Other constructor call way:

```
// SharedKeys constructor
SharedKeys::SharedKeys(*cstr)
{
    keyCode = keycode;
}
```

I am open to any suggestions for improvement. Thank you.

> Main.cpp

SK must be a pointer here or? (this code works)

```
SharedKeys* SK;

    vector<SharedKeys> StoreSharedKeys;

string str = x;
char *cstr = new char[str.length() + 1];
strcpy(cstr, str.c_str());

SK = new SharedKeys(*cstr);
StoreSharedKeys.push_back(*SK);
delete[] cstr;
```

Did I understand you correctly?

```
cout << "Key: " <<  x << " loaded." << endl;
string str = x;
char *cstr = new char[str.length() + 1];
strcpy(cstr, str.c_str());

SharedKeys SK(*cstr);
StoreSharedKeys.push_back(SK);
delete[] cstr;
```

if im see that correct then this contructor call is the right way. So i dont must delete the objects. Correct?

Comment: You just compared apples to oranges. Nothing is "called" in the second snippet.

Comment: The "other way" won't compile, and in any case is not a constructor call but a constructor definition.

Comment: There are some style issues here, such as intialization after definition (fix: `SharedKeys* SK = new SharedKeys(*cstr)`  or even better `SharedKeys SK` ) and the lack of initializer lists : `SharedKeys::SharedKeys(char keyCode) : keyCode (keyCode) { }`. But there's nothing wrong.

Comment: oh Thanks, i missunderstand the second code part. @MSalter i cant change SharedKeys *SK to SharedKeys SK. I posting more code for bether understand.

Comment: Why do you assume that things *have to be pointers*? Of course not. The only issue is this: A class has a default constructor. This is the constructor without argument and this one can even be called when not defined. So, ` SharedKeys keys;`  would be legal code, although it would create a probably inconsistent object (in which the members are initialized by their default constructor in turn). Executing `SharedKey keys; keys = SharedKeys(*cstr);` would first create an inconsistent object, then an object on the heap and then use the assignment operator to copy it to keys, which is inefficient.

Comment: Therefore, if you don't use a pointer, you want to create it directly: `SharedlKeys keys(*cstr);`. This is totally fine code. If keys would be a member of a class, you'd want to use an initialization list to set it like that. Also, you should think of deleting the default constructor, should it have the potential to create inconsistent objects: `SharedKeys() = delete;`. As for using a pointer, avoid that. At least with raw pointers. You'd need to delete it and if your forget this, that would be a memory leak. Use smart pointers instead. Hope that helped you with the "It has to be a pointer".

Comment: Have added code sniped. You mean like that?

Comment: @Lendoria: As I suspected. The correct solution here is `StoreSharedKeys.emplace_back(*cstr)`. In fact, the current code leaks `*SK`, which is the chief problem with pointers.

Comment: @MSalter Thank you, so avoid the extra copy. fine fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second "call" isn't a call at all.

It's an out-of-class definition. The methods of a class (including constructors and destructors) may be defined inside the body of the class, or outside. If the methods are defined outside the class, you only *declare* them inside the class.

One important reason to use out-of-class definitions is that you can then put the class definition in a header file, and the method definitions in a .cpp file.

Comment: Thanks nice answer!

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to create an object:

```
SharedKeys   sk( 'a');
SharedKeys*  sk_ptr = new SharedKeys( 'a');
```

The first line creates an object on the stack, and it will be deleted when it goes out of scope (e.g. end of function).

The second line creates an object dynamically, and the object will not be deleted once the scope is left. You have to delete it manually, using `delete`. Or, even better, use a smart pointer.

Which way you chose to create your objects depends on the use case, the size of the object (large objects should always be allocated dynamically), lifetime of the object etc. But both methods call the same constructor in the end.

Comment: I have so far thought that these are destroyed automatically at the exit. Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: If you forget something and the program closes. Do the data in the Ram stay until you are overwritten?

Comment: @Lendoria: Modern Operating Systems for dekstop PCs do clean up. Other cases can be problematic - server programs typically don't exit, and in embedded applications there might not be an OS to clean up after you.

Comment: As @MSalters said, normally the memory is freed when the program exits, but there are exceptions. My text just says that the dynamic object is *not* deleted when the scope is left, i.e. the block in which the object was created.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is probably in formule
you can write constructor without dynamic allocated memory

```
SharedKeys SK(*cstr);
```

or with:

```
SK = new SharedKeys(*cstr);
```

second thing which i see... you see to example

```
#include <iostream>
void function(char a, int lenght)
{
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
//  for (int i = 0; i < lenght; i++) printf("%c ", a[i]);
}
void function2(char *a, int lenght)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < lenght; i++) printf("%c ", a[i]);
}
int main()
{
    char tab[2]{ 'a','b' };
//  function(tab,2);
    function(*tab,2);
//  function2(tab,2);
//  function2(*tab,2);
    return 0;
}
```

your line

```
SK = new SharedKeys(*cstr);
```

this line give only first element array to constructor, i think it's not like you want. If you want give array char you should use formule from `function2` (from example).

EDIT:
Yes, you must delete object,

```
 delete[] cstr
```

and

```
delete SK
```